# Expected ')' error in xcode

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have created a `CLogger` objective C class and defined below macro:

```
#define CLogError(fmt, ...) [[CLogger defaultLogger] log:@"Error" format:(LOG_FORMAT fmt), [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], LINE, PRETTY_FUNCTION, ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

I am able to access `CLogError` in objective C files and call it. But above macro is not accessible in swift file. So I created a static inline method as wrapper for swift to call macro indirectly. But I get `expected ')'` error in xcode when I pass argument to macro. Same works if I hard code string in macro. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
static inline void logEvent(NSString* msg)
{
    CLogError("Invalid Json");// it works
    CLogError(@"nsstring");// it works

    CLogError(msg);// didn't work
}
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your `#define`?

Comment: `"Invalid Json"` is a C string and `msg` is an `NSString*`, is that the problem?

Comment: I tried passing C string and [msg UTF8String]. both shows same error. Here is the actual implementation #define CLogError(fmt, ...)    [[CLogger defaultLogger] log:@"Error" format:(LOG_FORMAT fmt), [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define CLogError(fmt, ...) [[CLogger defaultLogger] log:@"Error" format:(LOG_FORMAT fmt), [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], LINE, PRETTY_FUNCTION, ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

The `(LOG_FORMAT` doesn't look like it should be there. I think you just want:

```
#define CLogError(fmt, ...) [[CLogger defaultLogger] log:@"Error" format:(fmt), [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], LINE, PRETTY_FUNCTION, ##__VA_ARGS__]
```